# How to translate the term "unsupported" (software term)?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

I am trying to translate the term "unsupported" in a software sense. Several software packages just use "soportado", but it seems to not be a grammatically correct usage of the word:

> **soportar**
>
> Del lat. *supportāre* 'llevar de abajo arriba', en lat. tardío
> 'soportar, sostener'.
>
> 1. tr. Sostener o llevar sobre sí una carga o peso.
> 2. tr. Tolerar o llevar con paciencia.

(source https://dle.rae.es/soportar)

There are two nuances to the word:

### To refer to a format/type of file/content that is "supported"

This is commonly found in software descriptions "this program supports DOC, DOCX, PDF, and ODS files". If I had a document editing program that can open `.doc` files, but not `.docx`, DOCX would be an "unsupported" file type.

"Compatible" is one term I've seen suggested but I was wondering if there was another term that I was missing that would best translate this word, as "incompatible" gives me the impression of a more final/irreconcilable incompatibility, not that is a potentially missing feature/functionality. My understanding of the word might very well be incorrect though, and I'm happy to be corrected on this if that is the case.

### An action that the user is discouraged from performing (i.e. at their own risk)

This refers to an action that the user should probably not try to do unless they know what they are doing, and the software provider is letting the user know before hand that they will not offer support (help) in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a sentence where you would use such word? So non programmers can understand it better.

Comment: In my early years as computer administrator I was told that "unsupported" means "you can try doing that on your own risk, because if it is not working or the system is damaged, the provider is free from any obligation of help or repair"

Comment: There are several possible nuances, to the word, if I think about it, but the one I had in mind was a file format/type that the program is unable to open, because the software lacks the code to open the file and understand the contents. I'll edit the question with this and more information.

Comment: @Jdamian indeed, that is another of the possible usages of the word, where the provider will not give you support if you try it. I will add that nuance to the question as well, to have a more complete one, in case it is looked up in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I would add yet another meaning to "unsupported", that which refers to features which are not implemented in a software application. For example, "Internet Explorer does not support javascript trim". In this case I would translate it as "no implementado".

Answer (score 1):

Compatible es la palabra más correcta en este contexto, utilizar otra palabra sería muy forzado y no sonaría bien.

Aunque "soportado" también podría ser correcto, no lo es tanto como compatible porque en sí no existe un prefijo que añadido a esta palabra forme su negación como tal.(lo contrario de soportado en términos de software es no soportado, porque insoportable es algo totalmente distinto) y por eso suena peor.

La negación de compatible es incompatible, y ambos términos son aplicables en un contexto de software.

Comment: Jackes, esta respuesta aparece ahora en la cola de revisión como "low quality", por su brevedad probablemente. Para mejorar un poco la respuesta sugiero explicar el significado de "compatible" y tratar de explicar porqué piensas que es la mejor opción para traducir "unsuported'. A ti puede parecerte obvio, pero habrá usuarios a los que no. De hecho, **"compatible" se sugiere en la misma pregunta**, y el OP comenta sobre esta opción que ya ha visto este término propuesto y le gustaría saber si hay otro más apropiado.

Comment: @Diego totalmente de acuerdo

Comment: No entiendo el porque de los votos negativos, soy nativo de España y estudio ingeniería informática, usen las palabras que les de la gana pero no sean maleducados con la gente que intenta ayudarles

Comment: No te tomes los votos negativos como algo personal, simplemente quieren decir que alguien no está de acuerdo con tu respuesta y cree que puede ser contraproducente. Lo suyo sería que dejaran un comentario explicando el negativo, para que pudieras explicar mejor tu respuesta o corregirla. Pero no dejes que un negativo te desanime, agradecemos tu ayuda y esperamos que aportes más al sitio.

Comment: En mi día a día, traducimos "unsupported" como "no soportado". La pareja de términos"compatible/incompatible" **no** la veo apropiada. Un programa "unsupported" para mí no significa "incompatible".

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con 'no soportado' o 'sin soporte' o 'sin asistencia'. Deprenderá del contexto.